# problem with hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, perforce

I am using Hudson for 6 projects, and most all of them are configured as a continious integration. **I have a problem with one of the continious integration is not working**;
when somebody checks in the code in the perforce, it's not triggering the build. I restarted it twice and its works good but again I have the same problem.

Please can any one help us
Thanks

Comment: Do you have polling enabled? Check the images at http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Perforce+Plugin to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

Check your perforce polling log for the job in question to see if it's having some trouble. You can get to it through the link on the left hand side of the job page.

Common pitfalls when dealing with polling with this plugin include:

- Incorrect "Path to perforce executable" specified in the job config.
- Workspace spec is incorrect, so no files, and thus no changes, are found.
- Sharing client workspaces between jobs. In short: don't do it.
- The use of on-demand slaves. The plugin needs access to a node that is used to build the project in order to get polling information. If no nodes are available, polling doesn't work correctly.
- The incorrect use of the "View Mask" option can cause polling to stop working entirely. If you aren't sure how to use this option correctly, then you probably don't need to use it.
- There is a known issue ([HUDSON-2062](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-2062)) related to clogging/leaked pipes on certain operating systems (it seems restricted to CentOS/RedHat). If it works after a restart, but stops working after a few hours or days, then this is likely your problem.

You may want to contact the developer of the plugin directly, their contact info is on the link Sagar provided in his comment: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Perforce+Plugin, or file an issue [here](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/). Remember to include your Perforce Plugin and Hudson version numbers in either case.

Comment: perforce polling log is working good for other project.its happening for only one of the project.if some one make changes in perforce still its not kicking off the build in hudson.iam just wondering last night some build are kicking of the by scm change. i have this problem from last week .please can any one help us